# how can I query to firebase realtime database?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-sql

I am developing an Android app using the Firebase.
It uses Firebase Auth, Real-time database, Storage.

And the App has a search feature.
For example, a customer can search another user using this feature.
If there is a user "Yoonho Aaron Kim", user want to search this user using some keyword like "yoonho", "aaron", "kim", etc...

But the Firebase Query doesn't support all of them.
It provides only "startAt", "endAt", "equalTo" methods.
Plus, I cannot use these 3 methods at the same time.

Because of this limitation, I am considering another module like "Cloud SQL", "App Engine".
Is there any good ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

AppEngine is actually not a database engine, it is a "platform to build apps and scale automatically" and as such can connect to different types of databases: Cloud SQL (that you mention) a relational MySQL db (or PostgreSQL) or Cloud Datastore, a NoSQL database.

With Cloud SQL you could indeed perform some queries with a LIKE operator in a WHERE clause. With Datastore you will get the same limitations than Firebase database.

However, switching to AppEngine means that you will stop using Firebase and that you will go for another solution to develop and expose your APIs to your Android app, e.g. use a framework like Google Endpoints (https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/) .

Comment: Thanks! I have more questions, If I choose "App Engine", should I use "Cloud SQL" or "Cloud Datastore"? You mean because App engine is a platform, it doesn't contain any database right?

Comment: You can choose which db you want to use with AppEngine, "Cloud SQL" or "Cloud Datastore". Since there  In your case you would obviously discard Cloud Datastore (since you could not query with "LIKE" operator) and go for Cloud SQL. However, it is important to note that you are going to do some extra work if you go this way: you will have to develop REST APIs in order to query your DB, while this part is made very easy with Firebase.